# matplotlib without pyplot's global state

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to create two figures and after creating them I want to decide with one to save as a file and witch one to show. This seems like an easy problem, but I couldn't make it work:

I tried:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot

fig1 = matplotlib.figure.Figure()
ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax1.plot(range(10))

fig2 = matplotlib.figure.Figure()
ax2 = fig2.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax2.plot(range(20))


fig1.savefig("test.pdf")
fig2.show()
```

fig1.savefig works, but fig2.show outputs

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/volker/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 433, in show
    manager = getattr(self.canvas, 'manager')
AttributeError: 'FigureCanvasBase' object has no attribute 'manager'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./plot.py", line 15, in <module>
    fig2.show()
  File "/home/volker/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 435, in show
    raise AttributeError("%s\n"
AttributeError: 'FigureCanvasBase' object has no attribute 'manager'
Figure.show works only for figures managed by pyplot, normally created by pyplot.figure().
```

I also tried

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot

fig1 = matplotlib.pyplot.figure()
ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax1.plot(range(10))

fig2 = matplotlib.pyplot.figure()
ax2 = fig2.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax2.plot(range(20))


fig1.savefig("test.pdf")
matplotlib.pyplot.show()
```

Again, fig1.savefig works, but this shows both plots.

Comment: `plt.close(fig1)` would close fig1 so `plt.show()` would afterwards only show any open figure, namely, fig2.

Comment: Do you know of a way that works, even If I decide whether I want to show fig1 after showing fig2?  Because after plt.close(fig1), there is no way to show fig1.

Comment: Correct. That is not (yet) implemented. It is assumed that either you know what you want to show when working with scripts, or that you work interactively anyways.

Comment: Are you sure? Can you point me to an official source? It seems like a basic feature to me.

Comment: I guess it's fair to not take my word as an "official source", but maybe [this comment](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/14024#issuecomment-532804367) would qualify?